# How to correctly cast IntPtr into an array when using Device memory in Hybridizer

Tags: c#, hybridizer

I am writing some C# code for CUDA GPU processing using Hybridizer.
My problem is I do not understand how to pass objects held in device memory into Hybridizer code and am getting a `RuntimeBinderException`.

I have a Hybridizer entrypoint defined:-

```cs
[EntryPoint]
static void Multiply(Complex[] a, Complex[] b,float[] d,int len)
{            
}
```

This works fine when the Complex arrays are held in Host memory, but I am trying to minimse the data transfer between host and device.
As such I have previously transfered the arrays to the device memery :-

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int numelements = 12;
        Complex[] a = new Complex[numelements];
        Complex[] b = new Complex[numelements];
        float[] d = new float[numelements];
        int memsize = numelements * Marshal.SizeOf(new Complex());

        GCHandle aH = GCHandle.Alloc(a, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        GCHandle bH = GCHandle.Alloc(b, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        IntPtr da, db;
        cuda.ERROR_CHECK(cuda.Malloc(out da, memsize));
        cuda.ERROR_CHECK(cuda.Malloc(out db, memsize));

        cuda.ERROR_CHECK(cuda.Memcpy(da, aH.AddrOfPinnedObject(), memsize, cudaMemcpyKind.cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        cuda.ERROR_CHECK(cuda.Memcpy(db, bH.AddrOfPinnedObject(), memsize, cudaMemcpyKind.cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

        HybRunner runner = HybRunner.Cuda();
        dynamic wrapped = runner.Wrap(new Program());
        runner.saveAssembly();

// the following line gives a runtimeBinderException as detailed below
        wrapped.Multiply(da, db,d, numelements);

        cuda.DeviceSynchronize();
    }
```

> Message=The best overloaded method match for
>   'Program_wrapped_CUDA.Multiply(Hybridizer.Runtime.CUDAImports.float2[],
>   Hybridizer.Runtime.CUDAImports.float2[], float[], int)' has some
>   invalid arguments

How do I either:

- cast the IntPtrs to Complex[]?
- reconfigure the parameter list for Multiply and then access the array contents?

Comment: Hi. As such, I cannot reproduce. Your code should work as it is. Please note you can save the generated assembly (_wrapped_ objects), using runner.saveAssembly(); after the invokation of Wrap() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take the assumption that `d` stores result of Multiply. If that's not the case, you will be able to modify the code easily.

Problem is when you mix `IntPtr` (manually marshalled) and managed types (automatically marshalled).

You can see the generated wrapper by running `runner.saveAssembly();` after the call to `Wrap`:

```
HybRunner runner = HybRunner.Cuda();
dynamic wrapped = runner.Wrap(new Program());
runner.saveAssembly();
```

Then run [IlSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/releases) to inspect the generated dll and see all the overloads which are generated :

[image: generated overloads]

As you can see, there is one overload with arrays and another with native int.

the first one is intended for automatic memory management, while the second is for manual memory management.

However, you cannot mix both.

As a solution, you have to manually manage memory for your `d` parameter:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int numelements = 12;
    Complex[] a = new Complex[numelements];
    Complex[] b = new Complex[numelements];
    float[] d = new float[numelements];
    int memsize = numelements * Marshal.SizeOf(new Complex());

    GCHandle aH = GCHandle.Alloc(a, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    GCHandle bH = GCHandle.Alloc(b, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    GCHandle dH = GCHandle.Alloc(d, GCHandleType.Pinned);

    IntPtr da, db;
    cuda.ERROR_CHECK(cuda.Malloc(out da, memsize));
    cuda.ERROR_CHECK(cuda.Malloc(out db, memsize));
    IntPtr dd;
    cuda.ERROR_CHECK(cuda.Malloc(out dd, numelements * sizeof(float)));

    cuda.ERROR_CHECK(cuda.Memcpy(da, aH.AddrOfPinnedObject(), memsize, cudaMemcpyKind.cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    cuda.ERROR_CHECK(cuda.Memcpy(db, bH.AddrOfPinnedObject(), memsize, cudaMemcpyKind.cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    HybRunner runner = HybRunner.Cuda();
    dynamic wrapped = runner.Wrap(new Program());
    runner.saveAssembly();

    // the following line gives a runtimeBinderException as detailed below
    wrapped.Multiply(da, db, dd, numelements);

    cuda.Memcpy(dH.AddrOfPinnedObject(), dd, numelements * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyKind.cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cuda.DeviceSynchronize();
}
```

However, in your case, I would use the [ResidentArray](http://docs.altimesh.com/api/Hybridizer.Runtime.CUDAImports.ResidentArrayGeneric-1.html) type, exposed by Hybridizer. They are meant to help you with that kind of issues.

```
[EntryPoint]
static void Multiply(ResidentArrayGeneric<Complex> a, ResidentArrayGeneric<Complex> b, FloatResidentArray d, int len)
{

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int numelements = 12;
    var a = new ResidentArrayGeneric<Complex>(numelements);
    var b = new ResidentArrayGeneric<Complex>(numelements);
    var d = new FloatResidentArray(numelements);

    // populate a and b

    a.RefreshDevice();
    b.RefreshDevice();


    HybRunner runner = HybRunner.Cuda();
    dynamic wrapped = runner.Wrap(new Program());
    runner.saveAssembly();

    // the following line gives a runtimeBinderException as detailed below
    wrapped.Multiply(a, b, d, numelements);

    d.RefreshHost();

    cuda.DeviceSynchronize();
}
```

You can find a more elaborate sample with ResidentArrays [here](https://github.com/altimesh/hybridizer-basic-samples/tree/master/HybridizerBasicSamples_CUDA101/3.Maths/ConjugateGradient)

Comment: Thanks Regis, 
Quick follow on question,
If I am using ResidentArrayGeneric to pass data back and forth between the device and the host, Can I be confident that say the host copy will remain intact (and unchanged) after calling RefreshDevice() and vice versa?